# connecting Sqoop to mysql

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have installed sqoop but now the problem is how to interact with mysql using sqoop I am new to sqoop and is it necessary to install HBase while working with Sqoop.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: RTFM. You can use Sqoop to import data directly into HDFS.

Comment: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/index.html - in case you are not able to find M in RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Download mysql to hdfs jar file.if you are using oracle db as feed file then have to get related jar file for oracle then put it in the below mentioned path

Then put it in usr/bin/lib/sqoop.

Now try to sqoop commands definitly it will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

You got to do your homework before asking questions in this forum. Sqoop is to get the data from RDBMS to HDFS.

Comment: And you got to read the rules before posting comments in the answer section. And who says it's only RDBMS to HDFS???

Answer (score 0):

HBase is not required. When you execute any sqoop command You might get the warning that 'HBASE_HOME' is not set but it is just a warning. You can ignore it.

Use sqoop help to see what are the options available to import or export data.

```
hadoop@master:~$ sqoop help
usage: sqoop COMMAND [ARGS]

Available commands:
  codegen            Generate code to interact with database records
  create-hive-table  Import a table definition into Hive
  eval               Evaluate a SQL statement and display the results
  export             Export an HDFS directory to a database table
  help               List available commands
  import             Import a table from a database to HDFS
  import-all-tables  Import tables from a database to HDFS
  job                Work with saved jobs
  list-databases     List available databases on a server
  list-tables        List available tables in a database
  merge              Merge results of incremental imports
  metastore          Run a standalone Sqoop metastore
  version            Display version information
```

You can further get the specific command usage for example "import"

```
sqoop import --help
```

each command has several options to customize the operation.

Comment: Thanks Rags same problem I have stuck it gives me warning while running Sqoop help command that your Hbase home is not set.

Comment: Apart from the warning, are the sqoop commands working as expected? Share if you have any effort messages.

Answer (score 0):

Importing data from MySql to HDFS (basic):

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost/dbName --username user --password 123 --table tableName
```

Exporting data from HDFS to MySQL (basic):

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost/dbName --username user --password 123 --table tableName --exportDir dir/with/data
```

For more: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html

Comment: Note that MySQL seems to work, but is not supported by SQOOP.  We had errors when moving from the default HyperSQL metastore.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps as below in your interactive shell.

1. sudo mysql (to launch mysql)
2. Show databases;
3. Use **databasename** (command to select database)
4. show tables; (to view list of tables in the mentioned database and make a note of the table name you want to import in hdfs and make sure there primary key in the column)
5. exit;
6. sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost/**database name in which the table is present** --username root  --table **table name** --m 1

Answer (score 0):

All You need mysql "JDBC" connector. download it and store in sqoop/lib file

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename --username mysqlusername --password mysqlpassword --table employees --target-dir /databasesqoop/sqoop/
```

download JDBC connector/driver from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Not required  Hbase ,  you required only sqoop and  jdbc driver for the respective Database, place lib directory and run sqoop